New UI, but how do I revert back to my custom colours, fonts and other code preferences?
Moved to the UI, added the classic UI plugin.
Prior to the update I had specified custom colours for properties, parameters, functions, classes, keywords etc. I also have a specific font that I used and some other preferences. All of that has been replaced and my Dart code is now much more monochrome and I am struggling to read the new font.
I don't remember all the settings. I tried the restore option and that didn't work.  I have dodgy eyes so any help would be much appreciated.

Does it help if you copy your Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory from the previous IDE version to the current version? Make sure the same Color Scheme is selected as you used before in the Editor settings.

To get back the whole IDE theme
Open IDE settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance
Select Theme Darcula
To get back only code fonts and colors:
Open IDE settings > Editor > Color Scheme
Select Scheme Darcula

The best way is to enable backup and sync!  I can then simply restore my settings.
